# input file from command line

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, fstream, invalidoperationexception

I'm here to trying to take input from the file. If user run this `.exe` from cmd and give a filename like `example.exe input.txt`
then it shows the file and read. But if user doesn't give the file name then it run as simply program's run.

Program is running well when I give the input from cmd during run time it run perfectly, but if I don't give the filename during running this file and run simply `example.exe` an exception show me the error

> exception: invalid null pointer

my code is here:

```
// inputfile.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {

        if (argc > 0)
        {
            string filename = argv[1];
            ifstream in(filename);
            in.open(filename);
            if (in.is_open())
            {
                cout << "file opened, do something with file";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << endl << "You have Entered Wrong File Name Or File Not Exist in Project's Library" << endl;

            }
        }

    }
    catch (exception e)
    {

    }

    cout << endl << "do with the simple program";

    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic error is in the line

```
  if (argc > 0)
```

It needs to be

```
  if (argc > 1)
```

`argv[1]` is `NULL` if the program is invoked without arguments.

`argc` is at least 1, the first argument being the name of the program. When the program is invoked with one argument, `argc` is 2 and `argv[1]` is the first argument.

Comment: argc>0 means , argc != 0 and greater then 0, 
argv[0] is the name of file,

Comment: @user5517253, `argv[0]` is the program name. `argv[1]` is NULL if the program is invoked without arguments.

Comment: yes dear, it is the problem, 
when i gives the aurgument it work perfectly , 
but when  i don't give the aurgument it shows me exception, 

//string filename=argv[1];
if i make comment this statement no exception there.

Comment: @user5517253, that's why you need to use `if (argc > 1)`, not `if (argc > 0)`.

Comment: Thanks bro stack exchange is the best platform..!

Comment: @user5517253, I am glad I was able to help. Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

When there is only one argument(always the exec file itself, e.g. using in the way ./exec_file or just double click the exec file), the argv[1] would throw an exception.

Here are some tips:

1. Try to learn how to debug the code(IDE like Visual Studio, Ecplise or gdb).
2. VC++ is not standard c++, which means it only runs on Windows, not cross-platform. You'd better learn to use g++ compiler(linux).